# .htaccess and mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework/public_html/index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I'm getting "Internal Server Error". What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/framework/public_html/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework/public_html/index.php/$1/ [PT,L,NC,QSA]
```

`http://www.domain.com/sub/folder/me` => `[REQUEST_URI] => /sub/folder/me`

First, when you want to redirect (.*) it also try to redirect to itself that is why you have a 500 error. so by saying: if it's not (!^) `/framework/public_html/` then redirect to this URL.

**QSA:** Query string append means if you have ?var=1 it will use it and append to the redirected string.

**NC:** Non Case means capital letters and lower case letters are the same.

Comment: Well, the problem is, that I need slashes in it.

Comment: Yeah! It works! :] Thanks.
Could You tell me what the first line of code means?
And for what those NC, QSA tags are for??